# install ubuntu 13.04 along side windows 8

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I recently bought a AUSUS N550 notebook with windows 8 preinstalled.
Now I wanted to install ubuntu 13.04 LTS along side window8, but not able to do it.

I found lots post that say to disable secure boot. I went inside my bios setting and saw secure boot option [enabled]. Do I need to disable it?

I have attached my disk partition info in here so that you guys can see how my HD are partitioned in which format.

[image]
I have also read in some post that we should not make more than 4 partitions in a hardisk. So I made three primary partition and left one (537.80 GB) unallocated.

Problems:

> Inserting a Ubuntu bootable disk doesn't boot on restart.
>   Went inside bios but there is no CD drive so that I can keep it as my first boot priority.

Please help me in installing ubuntu alongside windows 8.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't said what sort of problem you're having, so it's impossible to tell you how to solve that problem. I do recommend that you read [my page on EFI Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) and [the Ubuntu wiki on the same topic.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) If those don't help, edit your question or post a new one with more details about what's not working. Oh, and the 4-partition limit applies to the old MBR partitioning system. Computers that ship with Windows 8 almost invariable use GPT, which is not so limited.

Comment: updated question with my problem.

Comment: what was the problem in booting ubuntu live usb?

Comment: Please describe *exactly* what happens when you try to boot. It sounds like you're saying that there's no CD/DVD boot option in the firmware's boot menu, but that's not 100% clear. If so, try using `dd` in Linux (or something equivalent in Windows) to create a USB flash drive installation image rather than a CD/DVD version.

Answer (score 0):

For install Ubuntu, you can make a partition of `20GB` with `Ubuntu installer`, format it in `ext4 with journaling` and set the mount point to `/`, this mean than you will use this partition like `system partition`(as C drive in Windows). From remained unallocated space make again yet one partition, not modify the size, this mean that you are set it to maximum size, format it in `ext4 with journaling` and set mount point to `/home`, this mean that you will use this partition for storage your data(photos, videos, documents). Click install.